# Python selenium click on cookie popup

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I would like to close the cookie popup in a page by clicking the accept button.
Please could you help?

```
driver.get('https://vaccination-covid.keldoc.com/redirect/?dom=cabinet-medical&inst=bain-de-bretagne-35470&user=salle-des-fetes-de-bain-de-bretagne')
time.sleep(4)
btns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'accepte')]")
for btn in btns:
    btn.click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `accept Button` is inside an `iframe` you need to switch it.

```
driver.switch_to.frame("Iframe")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'accepte')]").click()
```

---

Ideally you should use `WebDriverWait`()

```
driver.get("https://vaccination-covid.keldoc.com/redirect/?dom=cabinet-medical&inst=bain-de-bretagne-35470&user=salle-des-fetes-de-bain-de-bretagne")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"Iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(), 'accepte')]"))).click()
```

You need to import below libarries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

To jump out from `iframe` use

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tested your interesting solution, but it doesn't work on my system with both solutions. No click is done. Do you confirm?

Comment: @user3612078 : It is working absolutely fine on my machine. did you copy and paste my code and execute?

Comment: Yes I did!, so what can be the difference beetween us??

Comment: Sorry, the problem was coming from tle lines of code before those you gave me. Now it is working fine. Yours solutions are OK. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hi. Is this still working? I am not able to execute the code.